# Reddiag being a calculable function (Gödel, Escher, Bach)

Tags: computability

In [Gödel, Escher, Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) Chapter XIII: BlooP and FlooP and GlooP, Douglas Hofstadter states that:

> This puts us in the uncomfortable position of asserting that people can calculate Reddiag[N] for any value of N, but there is no way to program a computer to do so.

How come this is true? What if `Reddiag[N] = 1 + Reddiag[N]`? I understand how this is not computable, but how is it calculable? Is the idea that a person could notice that this is a sum of an infinite series of 1's, and either calculate that the answer is "infinity" or something like "-1/12" and therefore terminate?

Thanks :)

**Update**

The `Reddiag` is defined as `Reddiag[N] = 1 + RedProgram[#N][N]`, where `RedProgram` is any function written in a Turing complete language that takes one integer as an input, and we know that it is guaranteed to terminate with all inputs.

Comment: What is "Reddiag"?

Comment: @nirshahar I have updates the answer, hope it is more clear right now

Comment: Thanks! Can you please clarify the notation `RedProgram[#N][N]`?

Comment: Please don't use "Update" and don't just append stuff to the end.  Instead, it would be better to revise the question so that it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  In particular, I encourage you to define RedDiag before you use that term for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passage in question has a **standing assumption that `RedProgram` enumerates all computable total functions.** Since `Reddiag` is total and different from every function enumerated by `RedProgram`, we conclude that it is not computable. The text continues to reach the conclusion that the standing assumption is false, by a standard argument in computability theory.

Let me also address your question about `Reddiag[N] = 1 + Reddiag[N]`. This is not possible because there is no natural number such that `n = 1 + n`.

Comment: What do you mean by "total" functions? Terminates over all the inputs? Also, why in the book Reddiag is consider a "calculable", but not "computable" function? For instance this sentence "..._people_ can calculate Reddiag[N] for any value of N, but there is no way to program a _computer_ to do so", what is meant by it?

Comment: Yes, a function is total if it terminates on all inputs. The functiond `Reddiag` is called calculabe, by which the author means "humans can compute it", because humans can compute it. Sorry for a silly answer, but that's the meaning of "calculable".

Comment: With "computability" I don't understand what exactly humans can and machines can't. For isntance, when BlooP (non-Turing complete) language was introduced, he showed `Bluediag(N) = 1 + Blueprogram{#N}(N)` function, where Blueprogram is a list of all BlooP programs. Then he showed using the diagonal method, how Bluediag is not part of BlooP functions, and therefore whilst it is calculable, machines can't compute it. My understanding the reason was that you could not implement recursion in BlooP due to its finite loops. At the same times humans could carry the computation forever.

Comment: I thought he introduced FlooP (Turing complete language), because it is more "expressive" -- allows infinite loops. So now you could implement `Bluediag` and therefore compute it, by "computing" my understanding is that you calculate it forever, which is fine, because that's how it is defined. And I would assume by "calculable" it means that humans would do the same, calculate forever.

Comment: Unless by "calculable" it means, that human would simply conclude that "Reddiag" and "Bluediag" can't terminate, whilst a machine would continue forever trying to find the answer.

Comment: The book explains all of what you're wondering about very, very carefully. I could direct you to a computability textbook, which are much more terse and technical. Would that suit you better? I don't think rehashing explanations in the comments will lead to much.

Comment: "Calculable" means "can be computed (in finite time) by humans". "Computable" means "can be computed by a machine" (a Turing machine, to be exact). These two terms are not under discussion and are standard. The book uses them in this way as well.

Comment: I have "Computability and Logic" by Boolos, Burgess and Jeffrey, which is collecting dust, might have a look into it, thanks!